could anyone help me find out why this is happening with renpy?
I worked a couple of demos trying to figure out how imagebutton works.
all the sudden this demo version that I was fallowing stop working the call screen and the show screen.
I tried to reinstall everything and follow the tutorial and yet still causing this.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L9Vt7fcwkXk

Can you show us your code so far and then tell us what weird behavior is happening? Is it giving an error or is it just not showing the screen or something else?
